How to disable players from switching jumping midair before touching bottom ground or top ground
so I made a endless runner game(still prototype) with switching jumping from bottom to top and top to bottom. but the problem is when I click up button to switch platform, the down button still active so it still can move the player to switch on midair before touching upper ground. how do I fix this.
Here's my code.
public float jumpForce;
private Rigidbody myRigidbody;
public LayerMask groundLayer;
public bool grounded;
public Transform groundCheck;
public float groundCheckRadius;

void Update()
    {        
        grounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle (groundCheck.position, groundCheckRadius,       groundLayer);
       // isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.15f, groundLayer);

      myRigidbody.velocity= new Vector3(moveSpeed, myRigidbody.velocity.y);
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            Down();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(2))   
        { 
            Up();        }

        if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) && !stopJump)
        {
            if(jumpTimeCounter > 0)
            {
                myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(myRigidbody.velocity.x,     myRigidbody.velocity.z, jumpForce);
                jumpTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space) || Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            jumpTimeCounter = 0;
            stopJump = true;
        }
        if(grounded)
        {
            jumpTimeCounter = jumpTime;
        }

public void Up()
    {
        Physics.gravity *= 1;
        JumpSound.Play();
            if(Physics.gravity.y < 0)
            {
                Physics.gravity *= -1; 
            }
        if(grounded)
        {
            myRigidbody.velocity= new Vector3 (myRigidbody.velocity.x, myRigidbody.velocity.z, jumpForce);
            stopJump = false;
        }   
        
    }

    public void Down()
    {
         Physics.gravity *=1;
                if(Physics.gravity.y > 0)
                {
                     Physics.gravity *= -1;
                }
             
             JumpSound.Play();
        
            if(grounded)
            {
                myRigidbody.velocity= new Vector3 (myRigidbody.velocity.x, myRigidbody.velocity.z, jumpForce);
                stopJump = false;
            }
        
    }
    public void Run()
    {
       gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
```
`

I searched tutorials online on youtube and got recomendation to add ground layer to top ground and bottom ground. the narrator say this method can made the grounded turn on and off automatically so it won't switch jump midair before touching ground.and when I test the game it's won't budge even though I had already apply top and bottom ground with Ground layer[this can't on/off automatically ](https://i.sstatic.net/mLq3QQUD.png)


check its grounded to switch? (not sure what switch is, but if you need it to only work when grounded, check its grounded)

grounded already checked on but when game is strating the grounded don't wanna work and turn to off itself

Your issue is that you have conditions that overlap and you're only using "if's". You need to use a series of "if ... else if ... else if ..." in order to only execute the statements you want. Of course, you need to insure your if's are in the order you want them evaluated once you add your "else's". If you were dealing with a single "code", for example, you could use a "switch" statement.
